# Handling un-readable questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Yet another triage review queue story!

Going through the queue, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693218/custom-control-wpf-c-sharp) question that was posted by a new user. Now, in my time on S.O. I've seen my fair share of broken English. Usually my policy is to edit such questions so that they make more sense. However in this case, I have no idea what this guy is asking for:

> hello every body.  I wan't custom border or form same image. How do
>   can same image. Everybody can give me soem key Thank everybody
>
> [enter image description here][1]

That is their entire question body by the way, not just the worst part. What is meta's stance on this? How should this kind of unintelligibility be handled?

Comment: If I meet a question where I don't understand what is asked, I would ... let me think ... VTC as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: If it is broken to the point that it can no longer be recognisable as English, a VLQ flag might be appropriate too. But start with closing as *Unclear*.

Comment: For the record what he is asking is : "I want custom border like this image. How can I achieve the same? Everybody give me the code! ". So you can just flag it as unclear, unsavagable VLQ as you don't read the Almost-English. But for native monkey typer, it's clearly a give me the css code of image border.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not sure what good it does to flag a question VLQ *when it's already in Triage*.

Comment: I love the "wan't" in that question; don't think I've ever seen that before. "isn't, shouldn't, can't, don't, aren't, and even ain't, so why not wan't?"

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I guess that person just thought "won't" and "want" sound pretty similar, they are also spelled almost equally :D.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Don't VLQ flags go to the moderator queue?

Comment: _How do can same cheezburger._

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Just the other day I saw a post with "differen't". It wasn't a joke.

Comment: Issue seems pretty simple based on your own comment ... *" I have no idea what this guy is asking for"* . There is a close reason already for that exact scenario. Vote to close and move on ... don't overthink it

Answer (score 35):

It's unclear what the user is asking. So choose "Unsalvageable" -> "Unclear what you're asking".

Sometimes, a question is unclear to you as a reviewer, but might be clear to others. This is especially the case if it's about technology that you're not familiar with. In that case, it's better to choose "Skip".

But in this particular case, I don't think anyone can make much sense out of this. Maybe the user wants a custom border around an image using C# and WPF, judging by the tags. But then they should at least show what they've tried. So "Too Broad" or "lacks MCVE" is also an option.

Comment: Unclear is fine here. Too Broad is possible, but dubious. I'm not sure it makes any sense at all to close as lacking MCVE unless you're specifically abusing it as a ghetto "do my work for me/homework" reason.

Comment: In the skip case, sometimes it still might make sense to add a comment asking for clarification.